# Let $p, q$ be primes s.t. $3pq\ \big|\ n^{3pq} - n$ for all positive integers $n$. Find the least value of $p+q$.

Tags: number-theory

Q. let $p$, $q$ be prime numbers such that $n^{3pq} - n$ is a multiple of $3pq$ for all positive integers $n$. Find the least possible value of $p+q$.
Now, I do know about *Fermat's Little Theorem* which resembles to this, but that's for prime numbers as the power and here $3pq$ is composite ...
So is there any theorem equivalence of *Fermat's Little Theorem* for composite powers?
Or give me any high school maths solution to this problem .

Comment: Seems that we basically have to search the smallest Carmichael number divisible by $3$.

Comment: You could improve your questions by using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Peter … which happens to be the smallest Carmichael number altogether.

Comment: Peter or k.stm , can anybody explain to me how carmicheal number.......... ?

Answer (score 1):

As [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961/peter)'s comment indicated, you're looking for Carmichael numbers which are multiples of $3$ and a product of $2$ other small primes. As [k.stm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42242/k-stm)'s comment stated, it's actually the smallest such number.

Wikipedia's [Carmichael number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number) article explains about these numbers. The [Discovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number#Discovery) section states this smallest number is $561 = 3 \times 11 \times 17$, lists several of the next smallest numbers and describes a theorem to construct a subset of these numbers.